Transfer fuction in $\mathcal{H}_{2}$ space
I have a question on the explanation of transfer function and $\mathcal{H}_{2}$. I am trying to understand these using this material. It says the following:

$\mathcal{H}_{2}$ is subspace of $\mathcal{L}_2(j\mathbb{R})$ with matrix functions $F (s)$ analytic in $\mathcal{Re}(s) > 0$ (open
right-half plane).
The real rational subspace of $\mathcal{H}_{2}$, which consists of all strictly proper and real rational stable
transfer matrices, is denoted by $\mathcal{RH}_{2}$.

I am struggling with how I can connect the second concept with the first one especially $\mathcal{Re}(s) > 0$ (open right-half plane). I understand that strictly proper and real rational transfer matrices has no poles on right half plane, but does this something to do with these two descriptions?
I am new to this area so any comments and suggestion of materials would be appreciated.

Matt's answer is a good one: they are all subsets going from most general ($\mathcal{L}{2}$) to most specific ($\mathcal{RH}{2}$).

The Hardy space $H^2$ is a subspace of $L^2$, and $\mathcal{R}H^2$ is a subspace of $H^2$, i.e.,
$$\mathcal{R}H^2 \subset H^2 \subset L^2$$
$H^2$ contains all functions in $L^2$ that are analytic in the right half-plane. $\mathcal{R}H^2$ contains all functions in $H^2$ that are real and strictly proper rational functions.
Functions in $\mathcal{R}H^2$ have the form
$$F(s)=\frac{N(s)}{D(s)}\tag{1}$$
where $N(s)$ and $D(s)$ are polynomials with real-valued coefficients, the order of $N(s)$ is smaller than the order of $D(s)$, and the zeros of $D(s)$ (i.e., the poles of $F(s)$) are in the left half-plane. Consequently, $F(s)$ is analytic in the right half-plane, as is required for functions in $H^2$.

Thank you, I understand that the definition is getting tighter from $L^{2}$ to $\mathcal{R}H^{2}$. In the very last part of your answer, you say "left half-plane". Can we say something with this and a function $f$ being analytic in right half plane ($\mathcal{R}e(s)>0$)? I still can't figure out how $\mathcal{R}e(s)>0$ and the no pole in left half-plane are related....

@user1168149: Since there are no poles in the right half-plane, the function is analytic for $\textrm{Re}{s}>0$. Note that $\textrm{Re}{s}>0$ denotes the right half-plane.

I believe that I am missing something. Would you tell me why "no poles in the right half-planes" leads to "analytic in ${R_{e}}{s}>0$"? Thank you so much.

@user1168149: Any rational function is analytic everywhere except at its poles. Hence if there are no poles in the right half-plane, the rational function is analytic everywhere in the right half-plane.

I finally get it. It is so much simpler than I have imagined. Thank you for your explanation, kindness, and patience!
